# Array[i] = i++;

Tags: arrays, c, loops, gcc, post-increment

```
int main()
{
    int arr[5]= {55}, i=0;
    while (i<5)
    {
        arr[i]= i++;
    }

    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
        printf("%d, ", arr[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

why is the output ( 55,0,1,2,3) Not ( 0,1,2,3,4)

Ps: I'm using GCC compiler

Comment: An easy way to figure this ambiguity out is to just never write code like this :)

Comment: @Alexander seconded:)  Only teachers/TA/profs write such code:(

Answer (score 1):

This is undefined behavior.

Clang actually warns about it

```
warning: unsequenced modification and access to 'i' [-Wunsequenced]
arr[i]= i++;
   ~    ^
```